# CQWP blog roll Item Style for blog posts how to put a field in bold in xsl? or format others?

Tags: xslt, content-query-web-part

I followed this popular guide to do a CQWP of one or more blogs.

http://erikswenson.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/sharepoint-2010-content-query-for-blog.html

Everything works, except I would like to know how to make the Post title bold, eventually edit the date field to add 'Published on', eventually make the comments number as a clickable hyperlink to be taken to the page of the post.

I found this other page that added an attribute H2 (heading) to the display title but even tho I think I copied the parts I wanted properly, the whole CQWP crashes.

(apologies, there was a wrong link) this is the right one
http://www.justanothertechnologyguy.com/2012/03/altering-way-blog-posts-look-in.html

Basically I want to know how to properly edit in XSL. I have tried to place "h2" and "/h2" (with proper tags) where it seemed logical but it did not work

Comment: Can you provide your template so we can see what you've tried?

Comment: it is in the links I have provided. What is now (and working) is in the first link, what I attempted to add is the second part written in the second link (the one that is called <!--Start of the HTML rendering -->). I have tried both pasting the whole lot (changing the name to my style name) or only the title header 'h2'.